# Trigger on active window change for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, eventtrigger

I wanted to get this result as some sort of "automatic trigger" (sorry I'm new), instead of having to monitor for it every X seconds or so

So far I could only get it like the code below, but then, besides the "lag" I also need to check for it all the time, which doesnt sound very efficient

I saw a couple of similar answer but only for c.

Thanks!
Pedro

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import time

last_window = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())


while True:
    if a != GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()):
        """do whatever i want"""
        a = GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
    time.sleep(1)
```